# Send push notifications using Google console

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-console-developer

I did create a GCM account for my app to receive push notifications, now there is a new update which is mandatory for the users to download otherwise they will loos a lot of app functionalities due to server side issues.

So, when trying to send the users a notification to inform them about how important this update is, I couldn't find any way to send notifications in [Google console](https://console.developers.google.com) like in [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) if I'm using FCM:

[image]

and upon searching, I found some tools like [pushWatch](http://pushwatch.com/), but there is no tool that can handle this huge amount of device ids, also it whole fails if there is at least one single device is already updated and can't receive it.

**p.s.** the update contains a new server APIkey.

Comment: There is no option like FCM console in google console. You can only send update notification to gcm user by using server side script like php if you have there device id saved in database.

Comment: @AmitSharma yeah I can't see a similar option in Google console and may be you are right there isn't any at all, but may be there is someone that has some workaround solution for my issue.

Comment: Are you simply just looking to send messages without a Server?

Comment: @AL. yeah, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no option to send messages to all your users using the FCM REST API without specifying a target (registration tokens). The option to send a message to all users is only available through the Firebase Notifications Console.

---

So from the comments, if all you need is a way to send messages without an App Server, you could simply send a request [using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309674/fcm-with-postman-the-request-was-missing-an-authentication-key-fcm-token/45310143#45310143) or [cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664911/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-click-action/44665817#44665817).

Comment: well, but what about the devices ids ?

Comment: You mean send to all devices? Either you need to have all of them subscribed to a topic, or you must have all of them. There is currently no payload parameter or option to do this via the REST API.

Comment: yeah that's my issue, as I mentioned I can use pushwatch but for simple amount of device-ids, but with the huge amount I have I can't handle that, so my question is, are your way will allow me to send to all the devices-ids registered to that server APIkey? they already all registered but usually when sending from the server side I have to mention the device-id.

Comment: I see. Didn't notice that. What I mentioned in the previous comment is still the thing though. I'll update my answer with it.